# Factory Girl - overriding attributes of belongs_to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a Meeting object, and while doing so override the attribute of the Course object which the Meeting object belongs_to:

Here are my models:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Here are my definitions:

```
factory :course, class: Course do
    name      "Generic Course Name"
    description: "Very cheap"
end

factory :meeting, class: Meeting do
  name "Meeting name"
  course
end
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:meeting) do |meeting| 
    meeting.course.name = "other name"
end
```

However, I can't seem to override the course name from its default.  I can override the meeting name just fine by simply replacing meeting.course.name = "other name" with meeting.name = "other name", but accessing the belongs_to object doesn't have the desired effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about?

```
course = create(:course, name: "My Course Name")
create(:meeting, course: course)
```